# Angular JS - how to add checked input into array and how to remove after uncheck?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have following inputs in table:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="slection"  ng-click="addEntryToSelection(entry)" value="{{entry.defaultName}}">
```

How can i get which items are cheked and get their values after button ng-click or how can i add value into array if is checked and remove after uncheck?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

you could do like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="slection"  ng-click="addEntryToSelection(entry)" value="{{entry.defaultName}}" ng-model="toggleInfo.checked" ng-change="toggleChange">
```

in controller.

```
function toggle(){
     console.log('check!');
 }

 var change = ($scope.toggleChange==true ? toggle() : /*false*/);

 //persist the check value where you could assign to services;
 if ($scope.toggleChange==true){
     $scope.toggleInfo = { checked: true };
 } else {
     $scope.toggleInfo = { checked: false };
 }
```